# Splash for Scrapy only returns empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I hope there's someone who can help a newbie:

I try to scrape the prices of https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g189541-Copenhagen_Zealand-Hotels.html using Scrapy. Since those prices are loaded dynamically with Javascript I tried to use Splash to deal with the problem. But the outcome is still the same: Empty lists for the prices ( "hotel_displayed_prices"). The other items do all receive the correct values.

On the webpage I found two ways to get to the price with CSS selector:

- .price-wrap .price :: text
- .premium-offer-container div::attr(data-locationid)

both ways do not seem to work... or they do both and just splash does not.

for scrapy I copied all configurations from https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash into my settings file. I did also put Robotstxt_obey = False

when rendering the website in Splash 3.4.1 (browser window) it showed me the price of the hotels so normally it should work I guess.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import TestItem
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class HoteldataSpider (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Testdata"
    start_urls = ["https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g189541-Copenhagen_Zealand-Hotels.html"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 5})

    def parse(self, response):
        items = TestItem()

        all_single_entries = response.css("div.listItem")

        for entry in all_single_entries:
            hotel_names = entry.css(".listing_title [target=_blank]::text").extract()
            hotel_links = entry.css(".listing_title a").xpath("@href").extract()
            hotel_ids = entry.css(".listing_title").css("a::attr(id)").extract()
            hotel_displayed_price = entry.css(".premium_offer_container").css("div::attr(data-locationid)").extract()

            items["hotel_names"] = str(hotel_names).split("'")[1]
            items["hotel_links"] = "https://www.tripadvisor.com" + str(hotel_links).split("'")[1]
            items["hotel_ids"] = int(str(hotel_ids).split("_")[1].split("'")[0])
            items["hotel_displayed_price"]= hotel_displayed_price

            yield items
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
hotel_displayed_price = entry.css(".premium_offer_container").css("div::attr(data-locationid").extract()
```

Are you missing a closing bracket on "div::attr(data-locationid" ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! yes I did missed this one indeed. Just corrected the line but the result after running the script again stays unfortunately the same...

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at the behaviour under scrapy, and the prices are not returned in the HTML to a request from scrapy. What you're seeing in the browser (even Splash) is not the same as what your code is seeing.

I don't know scrapy well enough to work through this, but it seems possible to get what you need with plain old requests & BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.ie/Hotels-g189541-Copenhagen_Zealand-Hotels.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.content, 'lxml')
prices = [price.text for price in soup.select('.price-wrap .price')]

print(prices)
['€131', '€112', '€121', '€133', '€172', '€169', '€74', '€189', ...]
```

Comment: Indeed, it works with good old BS+requests.  I wonder why this works but not with scrapy and splash...

thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

For everyone with the similar problem: Here is my solution. However I do have problems with duplicates when I run the script.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import HotelinfoItem
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class HoteldataSpider (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Hoteldata"
    start_urls = ["http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https:"
                  "//www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g189541-Copenhagen_Zealand-Hotels.html"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 10})

    def parse(self, response):
        items = HotelinfoItem()

        all_single_entries = response.css("div.listItem")

        for entry in all_single_entries:
            hotel_names = entry.css(".listing_title [target=_blank]::text").extract()
            hotel_links = entry.css(".listing_title a").xpath("@href").extract()
            hotel_ids = entry.css(".listing_title").css("a::attr(id)").extract()
            hotel_displayed_price = entry.css(".premium_offer_container").css("div::attr(data-pernight)").extract()
            hotel_type = entry.css(".mb10").css(".label::text").extract()


            items["hotel_names"] = [str(hotel_names).split("'")[1]]
            items["hotel_links"] = ["https://www.tripadvisor.com" + str(hotel_links).split("'")[1]]
            items["hotel_ids"] = [str(hotel_ids).split("_")[1].split("'")[0]]

            if len(hotel_type) == 0:
                items["hotel_type"] = ["Hotel"]
            else:
                items["hotel_type"] = hotel_type

            if len(hotel_displayed_price) == 0:
                items["hotel_displayed_price"] = ["NA"]
            else:
                items["hotel_displayed_price"] = hotel_displayed_price

            yield items

        next_page = response.css("a.next::attr(href)").get()
        next_page_splash = "http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www.tripadvisor.com" + \
                           str(next_page).split("#")[0] + "&timeout=10&wait=5"

        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page_splash, callback=self.parse)
```